# Parse MP3 file in .NET v4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, mp3, c#-4.0

How can I parse an MP3 file to get its all attributes? Also how to edit and the attributes of the MP3 file? Is there any class available in .NET v4.0?

Comment: have you started using .net 4.0?

Comment: Yes, It is with Visual Studio 2010 Beta.

Comment: Did any of the proposed solutions work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those attributes are called ID3 tags. I do not think it is the scope of the .NET framework to provide reading them.

Here is some code from SourceForge.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/csid3lib/

Answer (score 2):

You might have a look at the [taglib library](http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/TagLib_Sharp) for .NET. It can do both reading and writing of id3 tags among other things.