# Is there a C# library that allows you to query mp3 duration and bitrate

Tags: c#, .net, mp3

I'm looking for an open source library (BSD/MIT style license) that allows me to extract the bitrate and duration of a MP3 audio file in dot net.

Any takers?

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492507/parse-mp3-file-in-net-v4-0

Comment: although one of the answers there, TagLib-Sharp, is GPL not BSD/MIT http://download.banshee.fm/taglib-sharp/

Comment: Use NAudio, or just Mp3Frame class, and this code fragment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383164/how-to-retrieve-duration-of-mp3-in-net/13269914#13269914

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NAudio](http://codeplex.com/naudio)

MS-PL license

Answer (score 1):

There is a wrapper for mpg123 on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpg123net/). I have never used it but from the description it looks like what you are looking for. Or the source can help you out.

Comment: mpg123 is licensed under LGPL 2.1

Answer (score 1):

You can try the C# ID3 library. It has a demo client which extracts a whole lot of information from the MP3 file besides the ID3 itself (including bitrate and length): http://sourceforge.net/projects/csid3lib/support